# Python driver.get - possible to make it work through a predefined list of URL's?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

At work we have a task which basically requires the following steps:
1. Open a URL
2. Click past an SSL certificate
3. Click a link
4. Repeat 20 times

I've worked out how to automate this task in Python using Selenium, however the code reads like this (This is just the start of over 200 lines):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities()INTERNETEXPLORER
capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True

driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\\Python27\\IEDriver\\IEDriver.exe")
driver.get("https://example.com")
sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Continue to this website (not recommended).").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Clear cache").click()
driver.close()
sleep(20)


driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\\Python27\\IEDriver\\IEDriver.exe")
driver.get("https://example.com2")
sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Continue to this website (not recommended).").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Clear cache").click()
driver.close()
sleep(20)
```

And it basically repeats as many times as is required to complete the cache clear.

I'm sure there is a way to loop these actions.. Like creating a .txt document and having Python read from it and use its contents as an argument in the driver.get() part. But I have no idea how to do this.

So far I've worked out that I could define a function that repeats until the list is exhausted.. But I have no idea how to repeat the function while using different arguments for the driver.get() command.

Is this feasible? I'm not really from a programming background and all of this is extremely new to me so I'm still getting a hang of everything..

Comment: Just to understand what you're trying to do: You have a list of urls. All of these have the exact same steps of clicking a continue-element and then clicking a clear cache-element? And you want to avoid handcoding this times x and instead use a loop that does this?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\\Python27\\IEDriver\\IEDriver.exe")

for url in ["https://example.com1",
            "https://example.com2",
            "https://example.com3",]:
    driver.get(url)
    sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Continue to this website (not recommended).").click()
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Clear cache").click()
    sleep(20)

driver.close()
```

Go through some python tutorials.